# JQuery grid is not initialized

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jqgrid

I have an AJAX response of Content-Type application/json and there is JavaScript code in one part of the JSON response for initializing a JQuery Grid. In the javascript code there is a comment like this:

```
/* comment */
```

I thought that the problem was that the line is broken (in my opinion by the IIS) so it resulted in:

```
/* comment *
/
```

But that was not a problem, problem was, that there was a value in the grid definition, containing \r character, so the grid did not initialize.

Comment: Is it possible to see that js online somewhere? I don't think IIS changed it, it must be something else on top of it.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, the problem was in other part of returned Javascript.